# Editable stroke text with HTML5/CSS3

Tags: html, css

I need to make an editable text wich has a fill and a stroke in two different colors to place over a picture background, something like movie subtitle, with yellow fill and black stroke. I found only tutorials and examples with canvas, but I don't think it's possible to make it editable, or is it?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to resort to the CSS3 `text-shadow`:

```css
#container {
    color: yellow;
    text-shadow: #000 1px 1px 0px, #000 -1px -1px 0px;
}​
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gMsTq/1/)

Comment: @NW Architect, yes, I know that. Unfortunately I don't see any better approach.